# Changing type using str() and int()...how it works

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, types

If I do this, I get:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = '2'
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(y)
<class 'str'>
```

That all makes sense to me, except that if I convert using:

```
>>> str(x)
'1'
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> int(y)
2
>>> type(y)
<class 'str'>
```

...why are my types only temporarily converted, i.e. why despite str(x) and int(y) is x still an integer and y is still a string?

Do I have to replace x and y to make type permanent with:

```
 >>> x = '1'
 >>> y = 2
 >>> type(x)
 <class 'str'>
 >>> type(y)
 <class 'int'>
```

I can see how it's useful to have the type of a variable permanently fixed, but as a new coder it's good to know what I'm contending with.

Comment: `str(x)` gives you *a new object*, a string object, it doesn't "convert" the integer object in-place. Strings and integers are both immutable, and Python is strongly typed. Note that after `z = str(x)`, although `z == '1'`, `x == 1`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this clearly.

Comment: While it's not directly related to this question, I suspect that you may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Thanks. Added to my reading list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're dealing with a new object. In fact if something is a `str`, `str(obj)` returns the object, otherwise `str(obj)` returns a `str` representing an objects `__str__` method, while `int` returns a reference to the `int` in memory. You can see this by using python's `id` function, which tracks references to objects:

```
>>> f = 1
>>> id(f)
4297148528 # your IDs will be different. 
>>> g = f
>>> id(g) # all ints share the same ID
4297148528
>>> g = '1'
>>> id(g)
4301500520 # a str of the same value is a different ID
>>> id(int(g))
4297148528 # this is the same int
>>> g
'1' # value at g hasn't changed
>>> h = g
>>> id(h)
4301500520 # if you assign a value to a new variable, then you get the same ID
>>> h = int(g) # now cast it back to an int
>>> id(h)
4297148528
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I found it very useful.

Comment: >>> id(y) 3886159424 >>> id(x) 3894234088 >>> id(int(y)) 3894234104 >>> id(str(x)) 3886159456 ...  my IDs are different, thank you. Makes total sense.

Answer (score 3):

`str(X)` and `int(X)` are returning a new object/value of a given parameter.
If you want to change the typ of a variable then you need to safe the new outcoming object like this:

```
x = 1
x = str(x)
type(x)
>>   <class 'str'>
```